# How do I save a storage file to a location that the user chooses in UWP?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm opening a file via:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(storageFile, options);
```

The documentation for [LaunchFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync) says:

> When the launch fails for any of the above reasons, the API succeeds
>   and returns FALSE from its asynchronous operation. Since it has no
>   ability to query whether the above restrictions apply to the current
>   launch, the calling app should not assume that the launch succeeded,
>   and should provide fallback mechanism in case it failed. **A possible
>   solution would be to ask the user to save the file and direct the user
>   to open it in the desktop**.

What's the most straightforward way to do that?

I tried:

```
var picker = new FolderPicker();
var pfolder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(pfolder);

var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(pfolder.Path);
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(storageFile.Name);
using (var writer = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    await writer.WriteAsync(storageFile,0,0);
}
```

But unfortuantely `writer.WriteAsync` only takes `Bytes[]` and not the `StorageFile`. How do I get my StorageFile saved?

Comment: I read that as, if LaunchFileAsync fails you should say "hey user, I can't open that file, please save a copy to the desktop instead"

Comment: @Jason : In my app I receive a file towards which the user didn't have access before. Normally, I want the user to be able to open the file directly. This suggestion makes me think that I should give the user a way to save the file when the file can't be opened directly.

Comment: so your app saves the original file, then calls LaunchFileAsync() to open it in another app?

Comment: @Jason : I save the original file in a temp folder that I regularly clean.

Comment: I don't understand your  above code. The code is to ask user to pick the folder. But afterwards you are trying to create a file under that folder.  Which file do you expect to get from user's selection? To save a file we can use any methods from writer, but at least we need to get the file we need first. Your code is actually not reasonable in my point of view, what about have a look at this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

Comment: By the way, I agree with Jason that the doc is saying that if you meet a failure you should give user the way to save and open file with pickers. Although your user seems do not have permission based on your comment.

Comment: You can use the [CopyAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.copyasync) method to create a copy of a `StorageFile` in a specified folder. This is the same thing as "saving" a `StorageFile`.